# How to get values from Nested foreach loop (load Products category-wise) in php page?

Tags: php, arrays

> I want to fetch all the values to show them php front-end page. I have
>   two tables in database.
>   1) Category - cat_id, cat_name; 2)product - pro_id, cat_id, cat_name, pro_name, price;
>
> My **product.php** file code :

```
<div class="content">
                <div class="content_top">
                   <?php
                      $product = new Product();
                      $getProduct = $product->getAllProduct();
                        if(!empty($getProduct)){
                            foreach($getProduct as $categoryName) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h3>Latest from <?php echo $categoryName['cat_name']; ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <?php foreach($getProduct['cat_name'] as $detail=> $row){?>
               <div class="section group">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['product_id']?></h2>
                    <h2><?php echo $row['product_name']?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $row['price']?></p>
               </div>
                  <?php  } } } ?>           
            </div>
```

> My **Product.php class** file code :

```
public function getAllProduct(){
        $query = "SELECT p.*, c.cat_name, b.brand_name
                  FROM product as p, category as c, brand as b
                  WHERE p.cat_id = c.cat_id AND p.brand_id= b.brand_id 
                  ORDER BY p.product_id DESC";

        $data = $this->db->select($query);
        $result = $data->fetch_all();
        $product = array();
        $product1  = array();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $product[$row[2]] = array(
                'cat_id' => $row[2],
                'cat_name' => $row[8]
            );
            $product1[$row[2]][$row[0]] = array(
                'product_id' => $row[0],
                'product_name' => $row[1],
                'price' => $row[5]
            );
        }
        $product2 =array();
        foreach($product as $id=> $val ) {
            $tmp = array(
                $id => array(
                    'cat_id' => $val['cat_id'],
                    'cat_name' => $val['cat_name'],
                    'product' => $product1[$id],
            ));
            array_push($product2, $tmp);
        }
        return $product2;
    }
```

**

> But output is showing error like below: Latest from Notice: Undefined
>   index: cat_name in line 10 Notice: Undefined index: cat_name in line
>   13 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 13

**

Comment: Can you copy print_r or var_dump output just before the error?

Comment: same as undefined index error

Comment: your getAllProduct() method returning a two dimensional array and you're accessing it as simple array.

Comment: can you please teach me where to change?

Comment: replace this foreach with $key=>$value foreach and then fetch cat_name from $value array. you're facing this issue as you have created product array with $row[2]  key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two issues there :

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $product[$row[2]] = array(
        'cat_id' => $row[2],
        'cat_name' => $row[8]
    );
    $product1[$row[2]][$row[0]] = array(
        'product_id' => $row[0],
        'product_name' => $row[1],
        'price' => $row[5]
    );
}
```

Don't use the indexes, use the string keys. That way, you'll know what data you are using just by looking at what key is called, it's will be harder to make mistakes. Also, by using the numeric indexes, changing the order of the fields you select in the query, or simply adding/removing one will screw up your code since the indexes will index different informations.

```
foreach($product as $id=> $val ) {
    $tmp = array(
        $id => array(
            'cat_id' => $val['cat_id'],
            'cat_name' => $val['cat_name'],
            'product' => $product1[$id],
    ));
    array_push($product2, $tmp);
}
```

By doing this, the output of `$product2` will look like that - assuming the ids of the entries you get are successive :

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'cat_id' => '<some id>',
            'cat_name' => '<some name>',
            'product' => array(
                'product_id' => '<some id>',
                'product_name' => '<some name>',
                'price' => '<some price>'
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        1 => array(
            'cat_id' => '<some id>',
            'cat_name' => '<some name>',
            'product' => array(
                'product_id' => '<some id>',
                'product_name' => '<some name>',
                'price' => '<some price>'
            )
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        2 => array(
            'cat_id' => '<some id>',
            'cat_name' => '<some name>',
            'product' => array(
                'product_id' => '<some id>',
                'product_name' => '<some name>',
                'price' => '<some price>'
            )
        )
    ),
    3 => array(
        3 => array(
            'cat_id' => '<some id>',
            'cat_name' => '<some name>',
            'product' => array(
                'product_id' => '<some id>',
                'product_name' => '<some name>',
                'price' => '<some price>'
            )
        )
    ),
    etc...
);
```

Therefore, getting this array in your other file and using it that way :

`$getProduct['cat_name']`

Won't work, since `'cat_name'` is in an array in an array in `$getProduct`.

```
foreach($getProduct as $categoryName) {
    echo $categoryName['cat_name'];
}
```

won't work either, you aren't deep enough to access it, you need to foreach again.

You should put this in `Product.php` :

```
    foreach($product as $id=> $val ) {
        $product2[$id] = array(
            'cat_id' => $val['cat_id'],
            'cat_name' => $val['cat_name'],
            'product' => $product1[$id],
        );
    }
```

and replace the block from `line 13` of `product.php` with :

```
    <div class="section group">
        <h2><?php echo $categoryName['product']['product_id']?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo $categoryName['product']['product_name']?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $categoryName['product']['price']?></p>
    </div>
<?php  } } ?>
```

You don't need your foreach since you only have to look in `['product']`, which is already in `$categoryName`.

Comment: thank you...I amended in your way and Now showing error Notice: Undefined index: product_id in line 15 & Notice: Undefined index: product_name in line 16 & Notice: Undefined index: price in line 17 inside <div class="section group">

Comment: @japanyahoo you should post the output of the faulty array that you surely printed when you got the error so that you could know what was going wrong

Comment: These errors mean that these keys don't exist, we cannot know more. Can you edit your question with the print_r of the array `$product` so that we can see if the data are actually in it ? I assume that you already did check for that, but there is nothing I can do without that information.

Comment: thanks for your guidance. finally i solved it by editing below code:<?php foreach($categoryName['product'] as $product) { ?><div class="section group">
        <h2><?php echo $product['product_id']?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo$product['product_name']?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $product['price']?></p>
    </div>
<?php  } } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bidimensional array:

```
$tmp = array(
            $id => array(
                'cat_id' => $val['cat_id'],
                'cat_name' => $val['cat_name'],
                'product' => $product1[$id],
        ));
```

But accessing it as is was a unidimensional one:

```
echo  $categoryName['cat_name']
```

First, var_dump your array to see exactly the data it contains. Then access it proper depth.

Comment: Now showing error like below: Latest from Notice: Undefined offset:0 in line 10 Notice: Undefined index: cat_name in line 13 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 13

Comment: Do this $getProduct = $product->getAllProduct(); var_dump($getProduct) and please add the resulting array in your question